# How to freeze some row in ext gridpanel when sort happen

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext.net, gridpanel

like pic,
- i would like to freeze first row in my gridpanel while sort happed. 
- i have try to set data row value to when sorted, sort again.
so:

Q1. How to trigger sort by gridpanel specic column. like , i tirg it sort by column 上报金额.

Q2. freeze the first row which is get from control ajax.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvebm.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QqxJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

i have partly cover this question like below.
fyr.
- when store event have trigged, i done the loop for store data, 
after.
- i marked each row from 1...n and choose mark the special row 0 which also return data from control from dataSource behind.
- next i sort by this special column which is hidden.

- otherwise, the gridPanel exchange row have sort like before except my choose row. code behind:

  ```
      var SortChangeAgain = function () {
     //debugger;
      for (var index = 0; index < TabPanel1_GridPanel1.store.data.items.length; index++) {
          var i = index;
          var store = TabPanel1_GridPanel1.store;
          store.data.items[index].data["RowNum"] = i + 1;
      };

      var tmpRecord = store.findRecord("ReasonName", "合计");
      tmpRecord.data["RowNum"] = 0;

      store.sort('RowNum', 'asc');
      //TabPanel1_GridPanel1.view.refresh();

  };
  ```